# Semantic similarity among documents to do clustering in Python

Tags: nlp, semantic-ui, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

I have around 1000 documents(text like paragraphs). I want to find similarities among the documents to cluster the documents. Finally, I want to do hierarchical clustering. I want to implement in Python. How to proceed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad and is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. See [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-hierarchical-clustering-tutorial-in-Python) for some tutorials on how to do hierarchical document clustering.

Comment: My question is not too broad. I have to solve a problem but the exact problem cannot be discussed. But what all I need is asked in the question. I am not sure what is considered off-topic in stack overflow.